# Private and privileged methods vs prototype methods

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

In JavaScript I can create private and privileged methods by declaring them in the constructor. By this I have to move them out of the prototype of the object. Then I lose the possibility of inheritance and some performance since every object will have it's own copy of those methods instead of accessing one prototype object.

So my question now is what might be a petter pattern: Make use of private and privileged methods or not. I am no big fan of dangling so I want to avoid this. So what to do?

What are your experiences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen any value in creating so-called 'private' functions in JavaScript. Just mark them somehow to indicate that they're not part of your public API, and so API clients aren't guaranteed that the function will exist, or have the same implementation in a future version.

Apart from API consistency, there's no reason not to let people just use your private functions if they want to. Sure, it allows co-existing scripts to fuddle with your private functions, but those scripts could've already overridden your public API functions, anyway.

The accepted answer to this question has good commentary on this:
[Private functions in namespaced javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841268/private-functions-in-namespaced-javascript)

Comment: I would add that namespacing is a good idea fore anything meant to be shared in terms of JS.  Also, emulating OO-style inheritance is a horrible pattern to try to use in JS. SOLID is probably better, but nothing is perfect.

Comment: For top-level implementations shared between a small-team of people private members are probably negligible, but anything like a library with a large distributed user base will benefit from private members: especially when using an IDE with code completion.

Answer (score 4):

Convention would be to scope what is needed out... and for psuedo private or protected members to prefix your methods or properties with an underscore.

I prefer a psuedo private/protected scope...

```
var MyObject = (function(){
  var interalStaticVar;

  function ctor(arg1, arg2) {
    //create psuedo-protected context
    this._ = {};

    //create a psuedo-private context
    this.__ = {};

    //stash someval
    this.__.someVal = "hands off";
  }

  ctor.prototype.getSomethingPrivate = function() {
    return this.__.someVal;
  }

  ctor.prototype._doSomethingProtected = function(){ ... }

  ctor.prototype.__doSomethingPrivate = function() { ... }

  return ctor;
}());
```

I will say that trying to apply OO-style inheritance paradigms to JavaScript is asking for trouble and probably means you're doing something wrong.  I tend to follow more SOLID designs embracing the functional event driven nature of JS in the browser.

Comment: You could get more elegant and use this['\0xff'] or something else that may sniff badly.

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate private or internal methods and properties by using

```
obj._foo = private;

obj.prototype._internalMethod;
```

You need to seperate your private methods from inheritance. Anything that can be used without relying on inheritance will work fine. Also the pattern like :

```
function construct() { 
    var priv;

    this.someValue = foo;
    this.someMethod = function() { }
}
```

Here we ignore the prototype and write to the object directly. This pattern relying on closures to hide methods and variables works well with mixins.

Worrying about whether redeclaring methods in the constructor is inefficient is a micro optimisation and *evil*. If you don't expect to create at least 1000 objects the difference is neglible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to guess that you have some functions that are used in the constructor, but are not part of the public API.

In this case, one option would be to simply store them as a property on the constructor. Then when calling them in the constructor, you'd use the `.call()` method to set the context of the current object being constructed.

This way you automatically have access to public members via `this`, and to private variables if you pass them as an argument.

```
var myClass = function() {
    this.someprop = 'prop value';
    var privVar = 'private value';

    myClass.func.call(this, privVar);
};

myClass.func = function(priv){ 
    alert(this.someprop);
    alert(priv); 
};

var inst = new myClass;
```

So this just uses the `MyClass` function as namespace storage for a function that is used by the constructor. The constructor calls it from the context of `this`, which does something with `this.someProperty` and the `privVar` that is passed in.

Not sure if this is what you're after, but it is one option.

---

As correctly noted by [@Raynos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419970/raynos) in the comments below, any properties added to the `MyClass` constructor as simple namespace storage are not private at all, and can be accessed by any code that can access the constructor.

You could do some checking to help ensure it is called properly, like adding an `instanceof` check to make sure it is called from an instance of `MyClass`, but such checks are not at all secure and do not offer the protection of actual private members.

Comment: @Patrickdw how is that different from private functions apart from the micro optimisation at the cost of readability?

Comment: @Raynos: You've hit the nail on the head. It is likely micro-optimization and certainly doesn't help readability. It's just a pattern that could be used to achieve what OP is (I think) asking. It isn't necessarily good or bad, but whether or not it is worth using will be up to OP I guess.

Comment: @patrickdw in that case please always go for readability. Your always allowed to hand-optimise _real_ bottlenecks later.

Comment: @Raynos: I understand what you're saying and I'd agree that in most cases it would be better to simply use private functions. There are times though where it may make sense to avoid the additional overhead, in which case something like this may be worthwhile. Your comments and answer give a good counter perspective to this solution.

Comment: @Patrickdw your right this is a valid alternative but do mention that you can call that method in inherited objects which you couldn't do with private functions. I.e. call `Super.func` in `SubClass`

Comment: @Raynos: Fair point. I'll add a note that it isn't private at all, and can be accessed by any code that can access the constructor function.

Comment: @patrickdw I meant to say that if it's there you can make use of it any subclasses you want. This pattern is equivelant to a static method of a class.

Comment: @Raynos: By *subclass* do you mean instance? I don't really have any subclassing going on. Anyway, it's true that it is accessible to instances and subclasses if any exist. But beyond that, the fact is that it is accessible to *any* code that has access to the constructor, irrespective of any association with the constructor.

Comment: @patrickdw I meant multiple layers in the prototype chain. private methods aren't available as you go up layers in the prototype chain but methods namespaced on a constructor are. Private methods cannot be accessed like that. It's a good reason to use methods defined on the constructor.

Comment: @Raynos: Methods namespaced on the constructor are available as simple properties of the Function object. They don't enter into the prototype chain at all. EDIT: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/uWazJ/)

Comment: @patrickdw by are available I meant there always available because there public. I was trying to point out something like (http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/9aLvn/). The public access is a good thing when not abused. I didn't mean that they are on the prototype chain. Neither are private methods. The prototype chain illustrates what I meant with SubClasses (poorly at that).

Comment: @Raynos: Now I see what you're saying, but if you do `this.a = Constructor.available;`, then you're back to adding properties to an instance (which in this case ends up being used as a prototype object for a subclass). I think the point of the question was to keep the prototype chain free of extra members that aren't needed there without constructing redundant instances as private functions. But then I guess I'm not entirely certain what OP is after.

Comment: @patrickdw the example was poor. You can apply Constructor.method inside other classes where it is logical to do so.

Comment: @Raynos: Yes indeed. In addition, you can call Constructor.method anywhere you can get to Constructor, which is why I broadened my edit a little more to say that any code can call the method, which could include other classes, instances or from completely non-related code. Overall I think we generally agree. :o)

Comment: @patrickdw let me recommend the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) if you dont know already.

Comment: @Raynos: Yeah I know, but I try to stay away from it. I spend enough time here as it is. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I think it all depends on how you want to use your objects. If you need private variables/functions in some object, *and* want them to be accessible by the prototype methods of that object, you have to declare the prototype methods *within* the constructor (see [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zfuvc/)) by the way.

In my opinion it boils down to the design and usage of the program. If you need objects with really private variables or - functions, design it like the example I gave, otherwise don't. In my experience private/privileged functions are not really influencing performance.

Answer (score 0):

I typically follow the following pattern while creating the javascript objects.

```
var builders = (function() {
var privateMethod = null;
function builders() {
            this.a_priviledged_method = function() {};
            this.pointerToPrototypeMethod = __bind(this.prototypeMethod, this);
    }
    builders.prototype.prototypeMethod = function(){};
    return builders;
})();
// general method to bind a function call to a context
var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
```

Points to note:

1. 'privateMethod' is not private in the sense that it is not inside the constructor but by scoping it one can make it private for each instance of builders that will be created.
2. to make sure that prototypical methods are called in the context in which 'they are created' and not in the context 'in which they are called'. I have created a pseudo priviledged method that curry's the prototype method with the context at the time of creation. Subsequent calls to the prototypical methods will always happen in the context at the creation time.
3. As the method lookup mechanism of javascript dictates that prototype chain should be checked last therefore, 'pointerToPrototypeMethod' will be 'discovered' before 'prototypeMethod'.
4. One could have implemented 'pointerToPrototypeMethod' similar to 'a_priviledged_method' but in that case each 'builders' instance would have had it's own copy of the priviledged method leading to code copying.
5. While calling a private method one should make sure that it should be called by providing the context. For ex: in the body of 'a_priviledged_method' if one wants to call 'privateMethod' then it should not be called as privateMethod() but should be called as privateMethod.apply(this,args). The advantage being, if one wants to call a priviledged method from a privatemethod than it will be in the same context (to what the private method was called in).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
(function () {
    function privateFunc () { ... }

    A.prototype.publicFunc1 = function () { ... };
    A.prototype.publicFunc2 = function () { ... };

})();

function A () { ... }
```

I Edit: This doesn't help if you also want private variables.

Comment: -1 Confusing sample code. private function doesn't have access to `this` or private variables declared in `A`

Comment: If it had access to private variables in another function, they would not be private, would they? I find this comment confusing.

The private function are not methods but you can pass the object if needed.

Comment: The general pattern is private variables and methods in the constructor. The private method in a different closure does not have access to any of the data in `A` object.

Comment: As I said, it is not a method, it is a function. Any data it needs is passed to it by the public method.

Comment: Off topic from this discussion, but don't forget to make your immediately invoked function an expression. Right now it's a declaration, and as such, it can't be invoked immediately.

Comment: This is the best answer.  It creates a private context for a private method, and it define's A's public prototype methods in that same private context, so only they have access to the private method, which they can call via 'privateFunc.apply(this, args)'.  The pattern that puts private methods in a constructor is rediculous, not only for the reasons mentioned in the OP, but also because they're inaccessible to prototype methods, unless you declare 'privilaged' methods, which are actually public instance methods that defeat the purpose.  Upvoted.